# Nav bar buttons

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm trying to create nav bar similar to that of Uber's site.  Where there's a menu button on the left, logo in the center, and then log in and sign up are on the right.

I used  and div container="pull-right" and still couldn't get the Title to be center.  The buttons won't be stylized much more than what they are since they will be on a white background.

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <a href="www.google.com"<li><button class="Menu">MENU</button></li></a>
            <a href="www.google.com"<li><button class="TITLE">TITLE</button></li></a>
            <a href="google.com"<li><button class="Sign Up">SIGN UP</button></li></a>
            <a href="google.com"<li><button class="Log in">LOG IN</button></li></a>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>  

.nav{
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 15px 15px 5px 5px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
} 

.nav li {
    display: inline; 
}

.nav button {
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}

.nav a{
    color: inherit;
}
```

Here's my Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tokyothekid/r19y23ep/1/

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is.

Comment: Your code is not proper, You are using <li> inside <a> where its not closed properly

Comment: In other news, welcome to Stack Overflow. You may find it useful to do a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). I would suggest voting up answers that you think are useful and eventually you want to select a "correct answer" by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this fiddle 
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r19y23ep/2/)

in this i have manage the structure of your li and as per your description i make a design i hope it may help you

```
.col1
{ 
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:left; 
width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Quick answer

If you want something like the website for Uber, you probably need to separate the Menu from the buttons on the right side.

## Other notes

Also, HTML5 has specified special tags so code is more readable and organized, such as the `<nav>` tag to hold your main menu. `<div>` doesn't communicate the purpose of the container.

To do what you want, here is a to-do list:

- fix your bugs (`<a href="somewhere"<li><button>foobar</button></li></a>` actually is an error because of the lack of right bracket `>` at the end of your opening `<a>` tag)
- separate your elements into a menu, a title, and a couple of user account buttons

## The code

Here is a good example of how you could restructure your HTML:

```
<h2 class="top-title">Title</h2>
<nav>
    <button id="toggle-menu">Menu</button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="google.com">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.com">Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="user-buttons">
    <button>Log in</button>
    <button>Sign up</button>
</div>
```

This is a quickly hacked bit of CSS you might use to start with:

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
nav {
    float: left;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: none;
    position: absolute;
}
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: inherit;
}
div.user-buttons {
    float: right;
}
```

Add some Javascript, and voila:

```
$(function() {
    $("nav ul").hide();
    $("#toggle-menu").click(function() {
        $("nav ul").toggle();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/josmhansen/292p3xru/2/).